# How can I render Thai strings in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

Can anyone tell me how I can use Thai strings on Mac OSX in Photoshop? More than 45 different languages, including all the Asian languages, seem to render just fine. I can also render Thai in other programs, like Word and Excel and Chrome. Photoshop can even render thai characters correctly in the "Layer" palette. It just cannot render Thai characters on the canvas. Any tips on how to get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: By 'I cannot render' you mean it's showing squares instead of characters?

Comment: you can ask this question in adobe support center, they will reply you, here it looks like off-topic.

Comment: I could but stack exchange gets SEO'd so this question has a chance of being helpful to other people in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. You have to use the font called "Ayuthaya".

Answer (score 5):

First thing you should check is the Language Preferences.

Go to your `System Preferences`, and in the `Languages & Text` tab activate the `Thai` entry. You then have to activate the `Thai keyboard` when you start to add text in Photoshop.

Also, this might sound quite silly, but make sure you are testing it with a Thai font. Even if everything is set, if you are using a Western font all you'll see are squares.

This [Adobe guide on Asian type](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7580a.html) might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Some Thai fonts can be used on Microsoft programs but not for every design programs, I don't know about that much, but I have some free Thai fonts to recommend you to download. It's a font set [13 Thai fonts from SIPA](http://www.sipa.or.th/article_attach/font.zip). It's always be used by Thai designer.

Know more about the font set at : [SIPA Website](http://www.sipa.or.th/ewt_news.php?nid=481). sorry it's in Thai language, but you can Google translate it.